# Azure Logic App run trigger when Blob is added or modified - Status "Skipped" even with new blobs added

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-trigger

I have set up 7 logic apps for 7 different storage containers. The logic apps copy new blobs in specific containers to specific folders in a shared drive.

5 of the 7 work without issues.
2 of them report a status of "Skipped" even after a new blob has been added to the storage account container.

1 of the 2 containers with issues has over 50K blobs and the other has over 70K blobs. The others all contain under 1K each.

When adding new blobs to these 2 containers, I expect to see statuses stating "Succeeded", but they are always "Skipped" and the blobs are not copied

I have tried cloning and amending a working logic app, and also tried creating them from scratch, but the status is always "Skipped".

To test the configuration, I have tried editing the 2 logic apps and pointed them to newly created containers and folders, and added a blob to these new containers, and they work.

Logic App Configuration

[image]

Comment: Might be worth raising a case with Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks @Skin, I will see if I can open up a support ticket as my access is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Skin that to raise a support request In Microsoft Azure , but the design which you are using is right as I get the logic app workflow triggered when used similar design . Below is the design which is  slightly different and try this:

**`Design:`**

[image]

You can add more than one event too:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @RithwikBojja. My issue is that I need to trigger it if blobs are added to specific containers and not if they are added to other containers in the same storage account.

Comment: @ChrisT that too possible, below event type, there is another dialogue box where we can select specific container too, check it https://i.imgur.com/0ByYSHI.png